# My Network is rather predicts the mean output instead of individual predictions

Tags: python, tensorflow, regression

I am currently working on my Bachelor Thesis. I want to predict the heartrate of people with video data. I build my network similar to the paper "RhythmNet: End-to-End Heart Rate Estimation
From Face via Spatial-Temporal Representation".

My problem:
My network does not learn to predict the HR properly instead it learns the mean HR. Could you give me some tipps how to improve the variety of my Regression output? Do you have some general tipps how to improve the network performance?

Thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

According to Page 8 of the Paper, the output of the network is the mean Heart Rate. The output is computed with a mean pooling layer. Maybe you can get the single values from the single heart rates before the mean pooling layer?

Comment: Yes i know, but my network is predicting the mean HR of the whole dataset. I checked and prepared the data and now there is a relatively even data distribution. Still the networks predicts a HR between 77-82 for my whole data.

Comment: Puuh the problem is, a network is really complex to tune. Do you use a dropout-rate? What is your Batch-Size? Have you considered a hyperparameter optimization?

Comment: Yes i know. I tried using a Batch-size between 4 and 64 but it did not make a huge difference. I tried out different learning rates and amount of Gru/Dense units too but that was not the trick either.
I did not use dropout yet. Do you have any hints or recommended dropout values I should try?

Comment: You need to make sure, that every kind of data is equally distributed. For Example: If you have only 1 sec of video, where the person has a heart rate of 100 and the other time the person only has 70, the network will "learn" to predict only 70, because it has to high error to predict 70 wrong. If everything is distributed equally the error will persist high so the network needs to adjust its weights more.

Do you have a Dropout-rate?

Comment: The different training Videos have a equally distributed HR.

I did not use dropout yet. I will try it out. Do you have any good guides how to implement and improve the dropout rates?

Comment: ehm  you implement it after a Convolutional layer with a probabiliy (try 0.2 = 20%). THis helps that the each weights are more independet.